# Firebird upgrade from 2.1.3 to 2.5?

Tags: upgrade, firebird2.5, firebird2.1

Is there a list anywhere or best practice instructions for update firebird databases from one version to another (in my case 2.1.3 to 2.5.2)?

I have seen backup and restore mentioned. I have updated from 1.5 to 2.1 in the past but that just worked i.e. I just installed the new firebird version, however I aware that this was probably just luck.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

The Firebird 2.5.2 release notes has [a section on compatibility issues](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes252.html#rnfb25-compat) that you need to be aware of when upgrading. Also the Firebird install directory contains additional info on upgrading in `misc/upgrade/metadata/metadata_charset.txt`. If your database has the incorrect metadata charset things might break (but AFAIK they would have been broken under Firebird 2.1 as well).

Technically you can upgrade to 2.5 without a backup and restore cycle on your database, but that means the On Disk Structure (ODS) of the database isn't upgraded to ODS 11.2, which could mean that you can't actually use some of the new features (or: performance improvements) introduced with the newer version. This could be worse if you are actually still on ODS 10.1 from Firebird 1.5.